# How to use different GTK theme in chrome and System?

Tags: chrome, gtk, theme, gtk3

I want to use the Arc-Darker theme in chrome and Arc-Dark in my system but when I click on use GTK+ in chrome then it uses the default system theme (Arc-dark) but I want it to use a different one.
I saw an article (It was outdated) doing this in chromium but I wanna know that how to do it in chrome. Article Link: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=246528

I am using Manjaro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to run an app with `env GTK_THEME=Adwaita-dark /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome`.

Comment: I know that but what is chrome's app name I tried chrome and google-chrome but it's not working

Comment: This works for me: `env GTK_THEME=Adwaita-dark /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome`.

Comment: Thanks now it worked

Comment: But it changes back to default when I reopen it

Comment: Is there a way to make it permanent

Comment: ???????????????

Comment: Of course there is but how can I know how do you run your chrome? If you click on an icon - I can only guess, not using these things - you probably need to modify/override *.desktop* file which defines how to run chrome. I was able to google it in 3 secs, see https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/10/how-to-use-different-gtk-3-theme-for.html

Comment: yeaah nice I am using XFCE so I right clicked on chrome launcher then changed the command and added that Theme command in the starting

Comment: Thank you for helping me.