# Prevent LibreOffice from using system theme

Tags: gtk, theme, libreoffice

I recently started using Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon. I understand that LibreOffice automatically uses the system colour theme---my preferred system theme is dark so LibreOffice uses it as well. However, I want LibreOffice to use the light theme while keeping my system dark. I have tried searching online extensively, and attempted several of the suggested solutions, such as editing the `.desktop` file to include `env GTK_THEME` (such as [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/640817/how-to-use-different-gtk-theme-in-chrome-and-system)), but none of them have worked for me. Linux being so customisable, surely this shouldn't be so hard? None of the similar questions asked ever really reached a definitive solution, so is this not even possible?

### Expectation (light Libre + dark system):

[image: Light LibreOffice]

[image]

### flatpak

Some also suggest using the flatpak variant of LibreOffice, as it does not use the system GTK and instead comes with Adwaita-light by default, but I tried this and it didn't work either. It automatically changes with the system theme.

Moreover, although the flatpak version allows me to use a "preinstalled theme" (it comes with six), this is not quite the same as when Libre runs with the light system theme. Some bars remain dark, while the region that gets changed loses some refinement. Overall, it just looks bad (I have used grey in the example below, just because white is even worse and so is not what I want).

[image]

I would think lots of people face this issue, but can't find an easy solution!

Comment: Welcome, *"but none of them have worked for me"*, could you explain what did you do?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity I added `GTK_THEME=Adwaita-light` in the `.desktop` file for LibreOffice at all instances of `env`. This I tried in both the `user/` directory as well as the `.local/` one, as someone had recommended the latter to avoid resets with application updates. After saving the changes, I opened Libre but the theme was still dark.

Comment: I'm not sure there's `Adwaita-light`, but just plain `Adwaita`. Check the themes in `/usr/share/themes`.

Comment: Wow, that was a rookie mistake. Now it works. However, earlier I was also only changing the `.desktop` file of LibreOffice, but now I realised that I have to do it individually for the different programmes, or else the theme applies only when it is opened from LibreOffice (and not, for example, when opening a spreadsheet from the directory).